# Does using Observer pattern mean using simple state management?

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, observer-pattern, state-management

From here:  [https://medium.com/@ChanakaDev/reactive-state-management-with-getx-39f73527ce84#:~:text=Note%3A,the%20help%20of%20a%20method](https://medium.com/@ChanakaDev/reactive-state-management-with-getx-39f73527ce84#:%7E:text=Note%3A,the%20help%20of%20a%20method).

> Note: It seems like using the reactive way for the state management is
> more like automatically updating the states of the variables. But the
> simple way is more like manually updating the the states of the
> variables with the help of a method.

So, when we use Observer pattern in Qt i.e. we manually write code for connecting signals to slots and there are 'setState' functions which are called by us to update variables, is this called Simple State Management?

Does it mean that using Observer Pattern, we need to write code for fetching the changed variable state and then update the variable ourselves? So, Observer pattern is simple state management?

Comment: You can use it to manage states but it's more than that. The observer pattern came to decouple components by the message-driven approach. When a component changes and needs to notify others, it won't call them directly. So it will be decoupled from other components. Anyway, it's a good pattern for state management. For example, it is used in ReactJs to manage the components' states.